# Trigger created with compilation errors. Unable to find out the error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I tried to create trigger but it has compilation errors. Below is my plsql code

```
 Create trigger t1 before delete on dept for each row
 Declare x number;
 Begin
 Select count(*) into x from emp where deptno 
  :=old.deptno;
  If x>0 then
  Raise_application_error(5000, 'cannot delete row');
  End if;
  End;
```

Answer (score 2):

> it has compilation errors.

What environment are you using to create your trigger? Most clients should tell you the error message as soon as you run the statement, although some do make it harder than seems reasonable.

However we can always find compilation errors by querying the data dictionary:

```
select * from user_errors
where name = 'T1';
```

The only obvious error I can spot in your code is this:

> `where deptno  := old.deptno;`

`:=` is the PL/SQL assignment operator. The test for equality is just `=`. Also, the `old` namespace is indicated with a colon. So your WHERE clause should be

```
where deptno = :old.deptno
```

Also this is wrong:

> `Raise_application_error(5000, 'cannot delete row');`

`Raise_application_error()` must have a number in the range Oracle allocates for user-defined exceptions, which is -20999 to -20000. All Oracle error numbers are negative, by the way.

---

I presume this trigger is part of a homework assignment, because it implements very bad practice. The relationship between EMP and DEPT should be enforced by a foreign key on EMP referencing DEPT. Triggers like this do not scale well and - crucially - do not work in multi-user environments.

Comment: I have replaced error number with -20001, still getting same warning

Comment: @user11165861 - if you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
   BEFORE DELETE
   ON dept
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   x   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO x
     FROM emp
    WHERE deptno = old.deptno;  

   IF x > 0
   THEN
      Raise_application_error (-20000, 'cannot delete row');
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your answer will be more helpful if you explain how exactly it solves the OP's problem